# Что в java означает оператор ">+"?

Tags: java, операторы

Что в java означает оператор `>+` ?

опечатался в idea написав `>+` вместо  `>=` и код скомпилировался. Найти поиском не удалось.

Comment: Покажите весь ваш код и что в итоге получилось. Такой комбинации в Java нет, если только справа не число какое-нибудь

Comment: Нет оператора `>+`, это два отдельных оператора - `>` и `+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю, что вы сравниваете числовые типы данных, в этом случае вы просто ставите знак перед правым числом, т.е. на самом деле это два отдельных оператора. Например, вы точно также можете написать a>-b, переменная a больше минус переменной b (это будет аналогично выражению a > b * (-1))